# Reducing complexity and making it more readable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this NodeJS code which I need to Reduce complexity and making it more readable coz it has to many repeatable loops, and the api is very slow how do i fix this.

`````
const { PRISMA, moment, decodeHeader } = require('../../Config');
const { throwErrors } = require('../../GlobalFunctions');
const MOMENT = require('moment');

module.exports = async function (fastify) {


await fastify.post('/get-dashboard', async (req, res) => {
try {
  const headerData = decodeHeader(req.headers);
  if (headerData == 'error') {
    res.status(401).send({
      status: false,
      status_code: 'FAILED',
      message: 'UNAUTHORIZED',
    });
  } else {
    // let ref = req.body?.ref ? req.body?.ref : '';
    const location_id = req.body?.location_id ? req.body?.location_id : '';
    const filter_by = req.body?.filter_by ? req.body?.filter_by : '';
    const custom_startdate = req.body?.custom_startdate
      ? req.body?.custom_startdate
      : '';
    const custom_enddate = req.body?.custom_enddate
      ? req.body?.custom_enddate
      : '';

    // get custom start and end date
    let custom_start_date =
      MOMENT(custom_startdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000+00:00';

    let custom_end_date = MOMENT(custom_enddate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000+00:00';

    // get current start and end date
    let current_date =
      MOMENT().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000+00:00';
    //get start and end of the week
    let startofweek_date =
      MOMENT().startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000+00:00';
    let endofweek_date =
      MOMENT().endOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000+00:00';
    //get start and end of the month
    let startOfMonth_date =
      MOMENT().startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD') +
      'T00:00:00.000+00:00';
    let endOfMonth_date =
      MOMENT().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000+00:00';
    // get start and end of the year
    let startOfYear_date =
      MOMENT().startOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000+00:00';
    let endOftheYear_date =
      MOMENT().endOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000+00:00';

    // ```GRAPH CALCULATION FOR YEAR```\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    let query = '';
    graph_data = '';
    let startOfYear = MOMENT().startOf('year');
    let monthsForYear = [];
    let year = [];
    // Create an array of dates representing the start of each month in the year
    for (let index = 0; index <= 11; index++) {
      const add1Month = MOMENT(startOfYear)
        .add(index, 'month')
        .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.000+00:00');
      monthsForYear.push(add1Month);
    }

    // Get the actual amount for each month
    let statements = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < monthsForYear.length; i++) {
      let j = i + 1;
      statements.push(PRISMA.orders.findMany({
        where: {
          created_at: {
            gte: monthsForYear[i],
            lte:
              i === monthsForYear.length - 1 ? endOftheYear_date : monthsForYear[j],
          },
        },
        select: { actual_amount: true },
      }));
    }
    for (let d of statements) {
      // Calculate the total actual amount for the month
      let total = 0;
      d = await d
      d.forEach((el) => {
        total += el.actual_amount;
      });
      year.push(total);
    }
    graphDataOfYear = year;

    // ```GRAPH CALCULATION FOR MONTHS```///////////////////////////
    let startOfmonth = MOMENT().startOf('month');
    let weeksForMonth = [];
    let month = [];
    // Create an array of dates representing the start of each week in the month
    for (let index = 0; index <= 4; index++) {
      const add1week = MOMENT(startOfmonth)
        .add(index, 'weeks')
        .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.000+00:00');
      weeksForMonth.push(add1week);
    }
    console.log(weeksForMonth);

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the actual amount for each week
    for (let i = 0; i < weeksForMonth.length; i++) {
      let j = i + 1;
      let d = await PRISMA.orders.findMany({
        where: {
          created_at: {
            gte: weeksForMonth[i],
            lte:
              i === weeksForMonth.length - 1
                ? endOfMonth_date
                : weeksForMonth[j],
          },
        },
        select: { actual_amount: true },
      });

      // Calculate the total actual amount for the week
      let total = 0;
      d.forEach((el) => {
        total += el.actual_amount;
      });
      month.push(total);
    }
    // Set the graph data to the calculated amounts
    graphDataOfMonth = month;

    // ```GRAPH CALCULATION FOR WEEKS```///////////////////////////////////////
    let startOfWeek = MOMENT().startOf('week');
    let daysForWeek = [];
    let day = [];
    // Create an array of dates representing the start of each day in the week
    for (let index = 0; index <= 6; index++) {
      const addDays = MOMENT(startOfWeek)
        .add(index, 'days')
        .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.000+00:00');
      daysForWeek.push(addDays);
    }
    // Get the actual amount for each week
    for (let i = 0; i < daysForWeek.length; i++) {
      let j = i + 1;
      let d = await PRISMA.orders.findMany({
        where: {
          created_at: {
            gte: daysForWeek[i],
            lte:
              i === daysForWeek.length - 1
                ? endofweek_date
                : daysForWeek[j],
          },
        },
        select: { actual_amount: true },
      });

      // Calculate the total actual amount for the day
      let total = 0;
      d.forEach((el) => {
        total += el.actual_amount;
      });
      day.push(total);
    }
    // Set the graph data to the calculated amounts
    graphDataOfWeek = day;

    //```GRAPH CALCULATION FOR DAYS````////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    let startOfday = MOMENT().startOf('day');
    let endOfday =
      MOMENT().endOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T00:00:00.000+00:00';
    let hrsForDays = [];
    let hrs = [];
    // Create an array of dates representing the start of each hrs 
    for (let index = 0; index <= 24; index++) {
      const addhrs = MOMENT(startOfday)
        .add(index++, 'hours')
        .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.000+00:00');
      hrsForDays.push(addhrs);
    }
    // Get the actual amount for each hrs
    for (let i = 0; i < hrsForDays.length; i++) {
      let j = i + 1;
      let d = await PRISMA.orders.findMany({
        where: {
          created_at: {
            gte: hrsForDays[i],
            lte: i === hrsForDays.length - 1 ? endOfday : hrsForDays[j],
          },
        },
        select: { actual_amount: true },
      });
      // Calculate the total actual amount for the 2hrs
      let total = 0;
      d.forEach((el) => {
        total += el.actual_amount;
      });
      hrs.push(total);
    }
    // Set the graph data to the calculated amounts
    graphDataOfDays = hrs;
    // console.log(graphDataOfDays)
    console.log(graphDataOfYear)
    console.log(graphDataOfMonth)
    // console.log(graphDataOfWeek)

    // filter_by Day Week Month Year CustomDate //////////////////////////////
    if (location_id == '') {
      if (filter_by === 'Day') {
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gt: current_date,
          },
          ref: headerData?.ref,
        };
      } else if (filter_by === 'Week') {
        // 7 days a week
        graph_data = graphDataOfWeek;
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gte: startofweek_date,
            lte: endofweek_date,
          },
          ref: headerData?.ref,
        };
      } else if (filter_by === 'Month') {
        // 4 weeks in a month
        graph_data = graphDataOfMonth;
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gte: startOfMonth_date,
            lte: endOfMonth_date,
          },
          ref: headerData?.ref,
        };
      } else if (filter_by === 'Year') {
        // 12 months_for_year in a year
        graph_data = graphDataOfYear;
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gte: startOfYear_date,
            lte: endOftheYear_date,
          },
          ref: headerData?.ref,
        };
      } else if (filter_by === 'Custom') {
        graph_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 12, 4, 2, 5, 6];
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gte: custom_start_date,
            lt: custom_end_date,
          },
        };
      }
    } else {
      //if there is location id
      if (filter_by === 'Day') {
        //12 hrs in a day
        graph_data = graphDataOfDays;
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gt: current_date,
          },
          ref: headerData?.ref,
          location_id: location_id,
        };
      } else if (filter_by === 'Week') {
        // 7 days a week
        graph_data = graphDataOfWeek;
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gte: startofweek_date,
            lte: endofweek_date,
          },
          ref: headerData?.ref,
          location_id: location_id,
        };
      } else if (filter_by === 'Month') {
        // 4 weeks in a month
        graph_data = graphDataOfMonth;
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gte: startOfMonth_date,
            lte: endOfMonth_date,
          },
          ref: headerData?.ref,
          location_id: location_id,
        };
      } else if (filter_by === 'Year') {
        // 12 months_for_year in a year
        graph_data = graphDataOfYear;
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gte: startOfYear_date,
            lte: endOftheYear_date,
          },
          ref: headerData?.ref,
          location_id: location_id,
        };
      } else if (filter_by === 'Custom') {
        graph_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 12, 4, 2, 5, 6];
        query = {
          created_at: {
            gte: custom_start_date,
            lt: custom_end_date,
          },
          ref: headerData?.ref,
          location_id: location_id,
        };
      }
    }
    // ```Create new signup```; //----------------------------------------------

    const new_sign_up = await PRISMA.customers.findMany({
      where: {
        ref: headerData?.ref,
      },
      orderBy: {
        id: 'desc',
      },
      skip: 0,
      take: 5,
    });

    // ```COUNT THE NUMBER OF ORDERS```; //----------------------------------------------
    const orderCount = await PRISMA.orders.count({
      where: query,
    });

    // ```NUMBER OF CUSTOMER DEVICES```; //----------------------------------------------
    const ref = location_id == '' ? headerData?.ref : location_id;
    let [android_devices, ios_devices, web_devices] = await Promise.all(
      ['ANDROID', 'IOS', 'WEBSITE'].map((channel) =>
        PRISMA.customers.count({
          where: {
            channel,
            ref,
          },
        })
      )
    );

    // ```FIND TOTAL CUSTOMERS```; //----------------------------------------------
    let total_customers = '';
    if (location_id == '') {
      total_customers = await PRISMA.customers.count();
    } else {
      total_customers = await PRISMA.customers.count({
        where: {
          ref: headerData?.ref,
          location_id: location_id,
        },
      });
    }

    // ```FIND RECENT ORDER```; //----------------------------------------------
    let recent_order = await PRISMA.orders.findMany({
      take: 5,
      where: query,
      orderBy: {
        ordered_date: 'desc',
      },
      include: {
        customers: true,
      },
    });
    //----------------------------------------------

    res.send({
      status: true,
      status_code: query,
      message: 'Success',
      order_card: orderCount,
      recent_order: recent_order,
      billing_history: [],
      device: [
        {
          android: android_devices,
          ios: ios_devices,
          website: web_devices,
        },
      ],
      new_sign_up: new_sign_up,
      total_customers: total_customers,
      Graph_data: graph_data,
    });
  }
} catch (error) {
  const errors = throwErrors(
    'Something went wrong!!!',
    req,
    res,
    error,
    'SERVER_ERROR'
  );
  res.status(200).send(error);
}
});
};
`````

Comment: Please tell us what the code does. The title should be what the code does rather than your concerns about the code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). We can provide a much better code review if we know what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably slow because you're doing some multiple of 365 queries with a lot of overlapping (if you already have the totals for each day of the week separately, you already have the total for the whole week as well. Same for months). And some exponent of the previous amount of moment date wrappers.

If all of the data really is needed, then just grab the whole year from db and group by as much granularity as needed on js side (which will need to include the `created_at` field in the `select`).

If just the filtered data is needed, then just grab that and nothing else.

There is a lot to be said about the code, though:

- inconsistent naming of variables; sometimes camelCased sometimes under_scored. Might be a good idea to enforce some rules with a linter.
- HTTP response status codes are numbers between 100 and 599, for some reason you have the built-up query in there.
- etc.

But the biggest issue surely must be the number of queries.